# A way of direct peer to peer data transfer with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, p2p, end-to-end

I want to create peer to peer data transfer function in node.js. But I am worried about resource usage, when a lot of transfers happen at the same time. So far I used library named simple-peer and it worked well. My problem is that every time it has to go through process of connecting peers. Perfect way for me would be if every peer could connect to one network and then just send data to peers connected to this network using only their addresses (that are public). I want peers to connect only once and then send data to many individual peers. **Data** must not go through any server.
**Is this even possible?**
**Does any protocol exist for it and if it does, then what is it's name?**
**Can you recommend any library, or maybe it's possible with the one I am using right now?**
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I realised that peerjs library makes it work like that.